# Incorrect Error Message for Compare Attribute in MVC model class (for jquery unobtrusive)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Friends,

This problem is really annoying me from last 2 days. I've finally decided to put it on SO.

I have following property in my Model

```
[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Length of this field should be between 3 and 20.")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Password Lenght should be between 4 and 20.")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password did not match")]
[Display(Name = "Retype Password")]
public string RePassword { get; set; }
```

And Following HTML in razor to create input fields for the same.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
                </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RePassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RePassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Retype Password" })
                </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RePassword)
    </div>
</div>
```

It always render following HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Password">
        Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="Password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" data-val-required="The Password field is required." data-val-length-min="4" data-val-length-max="20" data-val-length="Length of this field should be between 3 and 20." data-val="true"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="RePassword">
        Retype Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="RePassword" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="RePassword" data-val-required="The Retype Password field is required." data-val-length-min="4" data-val-length-max="20" data-val-length="Password Lenght should be between 4 and 20." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-equalto="'Retype Password' and 'Password' do not match." data-val="true"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="RePassword"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its No matter what I write in `ErrorMessage` in `Compare` attribute, It always has same value for `data-val-equalto` attribute that is `'Retype Password' and 'Password' do not match.` for `RePassword` filed

Answer (score 2):

this is a bug ：[CompareAttribute does not use custom error messages](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401) and already fixed

download the fixed CompareAttributeAdapter http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/Download/AttachmentDownload.ashx?ProjectName=aspnetwebstack&WorkItemId=1401&FileAttachmentId=755657
and  RegisterAdapter

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute), typeof(TheFixed.CompareAttributeAdapter));
```

Comment: How can I update my MVC package..? In Nuget package manager, my all packages are already upto date.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very late so I'm sure you already figured this out, and since I didn't find any solution online that answered this question directly, I decided share what I did for the benefit of those searching for a solution:

Create a Custom Compare Attribute and apply your own error to it.

```
public class CustomCompareAttribute : CompareAttribute
{
    public CustomCompareAttribute(string otherProperty, string ErrorCode) : base(otherProperty)
    {
        ErrorMessage = CustomMessage(ErrorCode);
    }

    private static string CustomMessage(string ErrorCode) 
    {
        string ErrorMsg = ErrorCode;
        //ErrorMsg = Translate.Item(ErrorCode);  <-- My logic from database
        return ErrorMsg;
    }

}
```

Then in your Model you simply add your custom annotation (leaving out the word "Attribute"):

```
[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Password Lenght should be between 4 and 20.")]
[CustomCompare("Password", "My own message: Passwords do not match!")] // <-- Use your new Custom Attribute here
[Display(Name = "Retype Password")]
public string RePassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: The code works fine. If you're not seeing an error message it's probably because your view doesn't have a place to show them or you didn't include this code:   @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })